# What house came to aid of this character?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Season 6 episode 9

> Jon Snow and his army is saved at the last minute by an army recruited by Sansa.

What house was this? Were they previously asked to help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[House Arryn](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Arryn), led by Littlefinger as shown in the below screen shot.
[image]

Sansa requested their help in Episode Eight of Season Six. [Here's what the letter written by Sansa said](http://nerdist.com/reddit-sleuths-confirm-sansas-letter-recipient-on-game-of-thrones/):

> “[…] to protect me. Now you have a chance to fulfill your promise. […] **Knights of the Vale** are under your command. Ride north for Winterfell. Lend us your aid and I shall see to it that you are well rewarded.”

Here's House Arryn's sigil,

> A white falcon volant and crescent moon on a blue field.

which can be seen when the third army rides in:

[image]

Comment: Kinda makes one mad at Lysa Tully. Had she lent Knights of the Vale to Robb, War of the Five Kings would have gone much differently.  And her spoiled kid could be King of the Mountain and Vale like Arryns were in days before the conquest.

Comment: @Aegon It was Littlefinger who told Lysa what to do, such as poison Jon Arryn.

Comment: @TLP he did but she was the one calling the shots.... And she chose littlefinger over her blood and paid for it.

Comment: @Aegon Nope. I agree in the tv-show they made LF a lot more.... mellow. But in fact he is the one who started everything. He made Lysa send the letter to Catelyn to raise spite between Stark and Lannister, he had Lysa kill Jon Arryn, he betrayed Ned Stark, he caused Catelyn to accuse Tyrion for the attempt on Bran's life, etc, etc. When Lysa was going crazy, he pushed her out the moon door.

Comment: @TLP yes I know about all that how Petyr is the real player of game of thrones. YET the point remains the same. Lysa chose to send the false allegations against Lannisters, Lysa chose to poison her lord husband, Lysa chose to refuse to help her kin. She was an awful (though admittedly mental) woman.

Answer (score 7):

The banners (which depict a white falcon on a blue field) are those of [House Arryn](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Arryn).  Robin Arryn is the head of this house but he's a child, so Petyr Baelish acts as the Lord Protector.

This makes sense as Sansa is seen next to Littlefinger as the army arrives. Also worth noting that Robin and Sansa are cousins, through their mothers Lyssa and Catelyn, respectively.